# Using JavaFX in a Netbeans Platform application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, netbeans-platform

I tried to start developing an NB platform application that holds a `JFXPanel` in a `TopComponent`. Unfortunately, an Exception is thrown at runtime when the `JFXPanel` is instantiated. I saw that it's because i don't have the JavaFX native libs (like glass.dll) in the sub-directories of my project.

Before i try to solve the problem just by copying the files, I'd like to ask you if there is a better way. In my opinion, i shouldn't have to copy the native libs into my project because they should be delivered by the system my app is installed to.

Comment: JavaFX version? Netbeans version? JDK version?

Comment: JavaFX 2.1, Netbeans 7.1.2, JDK 7u4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How did you added JavaFX dependency to your Java project? Usual way is to add jfxrt.jar to dependencies, and in this case native libs will be caught automatically.
2. Another reason may be the wrong behavior of the lib copy option of Netbeans. Right click on project, then go to `Properties -> Build -> Packaging` and uncheck `Copy Dependent Libraries` option.
3. Also you can try to download [JavaFX Samples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html), open "Swing Interoperability App" and see how that project works.

Comment: I have a module which holds the TopComponent which i want to add the JFXPanel to. I added jfxrt.jar as a wrapped jar, but this lead to the error. I also tried to add the JavaFX Support and Platform non-API modules, but then i got a build error that says that the JavaFX Platform module is not a friend of my own module. Also, i don't see any option that is like "Copy Dependent Libraries" in the Path you mentionet in your point 2.