# JavaFx 2.0 GUI within the Netbeans Platform Application

Tags: java, javafx-2, netbeans-platform

Is there any way to integrate JavaFx 2.0 GUI within the Netbeans Platform Application? I've tried searching the topic but did not come across what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Netbeans RCP but it is swing based so you can embed your Java FX 2 components the same way you would embed them in a Swing application: use JFXPanels for the FX2/Swing bridge and then embed those panels in RCP the same way you would add a Swing component.

I have also seen

- [this tutorial](http://netbeans.dzone.com/javafx-2-in-netbeans-rcp) but have not tried it
- and this [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474072/using-javafx-in-a-netbeans-platform-application).

Comment: thank you for this, it is of HUGE help...at least now I've got something to start with

Comment: Just be aware that you will have Swing dependencies and parts of the application will be rendered by Swing, AFAIK. And the Swing dependencies might make it harder in the future to port the applications to platforms, which don't support Swing.